# How to use character string in R inside SQL WHERE IN statement

Tags: sql, r

I would like to use a string of character IDs in the WHERE clause of SQL query. My id object looks like this

```
ids
 [1] "0000000000000000010000001" "0000000000000000010000002" "0000000000000000010000003"
 [4] "0000000000000000010000004" "0000000000000000010000005" "0000000000000000010000006"
 [7] "0000000000000000010000007" "0000000000000000010000008" "0000000000000000010000009"
[10] "0000000000000000010000010"
```

I would like to insert that object into this SQL query:

```
student <- sqlQuery(con,
  "select
    FSAS.a_id,
    FSAS.grade,
    FSAS.score,
    FSAS.placement,
    FSAS.start,
    FSAS.completion

    FROM db.Fact AS FSAS
      WHERE FSAS.a_id IN ids"

)
```

I think the entire SQL query has to be a string but I can't figure out how to get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `paste` to create the expression

```
expr1 <- sprintf("select
 FSAS.a_id,
 FSAS.grade,
 FSAS.score,
 FSAS.placement,
 FSAS.start,
 FSAS.completion 
 FROM db.Fact AS FSAS
   WHERE FSAS.a_id IN (%s)", paste0(sQuote(ids, q = FALSE), collapse=", "))

sqlQuery(con, expr1)
```

Comment: Why do you load `sqldf`?

Comment: @r2evans While reading I somehow had a mental image of `sqldf` instead of `sqlQuery`.  Thanks for correcting that

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
qry = paste("select
    FSAS.a_id,
    FSAS.grade,
    FSAS.score,
    FSAS.placement,
    FSAS.start,
    FSAS.completion

    FROM db.Fact AS FSAS
      WHERE FSAS.a_id IN", ids, sep = "")

student <- sqlQuery(con,
     qry
)
```

Comment: Nooooo! (https://xkcd.com/327/) Please don't suggest this as a viable solution, it will break in horrible ways when `ids` is not perfectly compliant.

Comment: qry will be a character vector, the length of ids. Essentially reproducing the query, over and over. And none of those queries will be valid anyway.